# A program to determine no of minimum insertions to make a string palindrome in c language. Error i m getting is standard output missing

Tags: c, string, output, stdout

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// A utility function to find minimum of two numbers
int min(int a, int b)
{  return a < b ? a : b; }

int MinInsertions(char a[], int l, int h)
{

if (l > h) return INT_MAX;
if (l == h) return 0;
if (l == h - 1) return (a[l] == a[h])? 0 : 1;

// Check if the first and last characters are
// same. On the basis of the comparison result, 
// decide which subrpoblem(s) to call

return (a[l] == a[h])? 
                 MinInsertions(a, l + 1, h - 1):
                 (min(MinInsertions(a, l, h - 1),
                 MinInsertions(a, l + 1, h)) + 1);
}

int main()
{   
int n;
char a[n];
int x=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
if (n>=3 && n<=5000)
{
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("%d", MinInsertions(a, 0, strlen(a)-1));

}
else
{ printf("wrong input");
}
return 0;
}
```

PLease reply as soon as possible.
whats the problem with stadard input, in some compiler it is working.

Comment: In some systems if you doesn't insert a \n at end of the output nothing is printed. Add an instruction `puts("");` or `printf("\n");` before the `return 0;` in  the `main()` function.

Comment: I think that is better to use a #define instead of the `min()` function. The `char a[n];` declaration is not correct, is UB, furthermore n is initialized with an unknown value.

Comment: If ending printf with `\n` doesn't work, then add `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: @Lundin, Are you sure? I've never had any problems using `puts (" ");` as last instruction. I will check '!. However, yours is a right solution.

Comment: @SirJoBlack `puts` or `printf("\n")` usually come with a flush on most systems, but there is AFAIK nothing in the standard that says that they should. So an explicit fflush is needed on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one problem.

You are using uninitialized variable to declare `char` array.

```
int n;
char a[n];
```

That will lead to undefined behavior. Instead declare the `a` after reading `n`.